# Elasticsearch geo_shape query giving wrong results

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I am facing am issue, I know how to find all geo_points in a particular radius but I need to find how many regions or geo_shape a particular point lies in. To solve this issue, I have made following index:

```
PUT /users
```

And this mapping:

```
PUT /users/_mapping/_doc
{
    "properties": {
        "radius": {
          "type": "geo_shape",
          "tree": "quadtree",
          "precision": "100m"
        },
        "point":{
          "type":"geo_point"
        }
      }

}
```

Also following is the sample document:

```
POST /users/_doc
{
    "radius":{
      "type" : "circle",
      "coordinates" : [28.363157, 77.287550],
      "radius" : "100km"
    },
    "point":{
      "lat" : 28.363157,
      "lon": 77.287550
    }

}
```

The query I am making is:

```
POST /users/_search
{
    "query":{
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "radius": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "point",
                            "coordinates" : [29.363157, 77.28755]
                        },
                        "relation": "contains"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the distance between the latlongs in query and doc is almost 110-112kms, hence above query returns exact result, but when I query `[30.363157, 77.28755]`, it still returns the document even when the distance is over 220kms.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've mapped the circle and the second point (30.363157, 77.28755) and the latter falls well within the circle. You can see it here: https://gist.github.com/consulthys/5ec4c720faa69462cbee5f3e16dfd418

Comment: I think your map is wrong, 30.363157, 77.28755 lies some where in India!
Is it possible for you to tell me how are you making this map?

Comment: see https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EqLsYKiscQHRSTt243w8iQStvswHSFLW&usp=sharing

Comment: I guess I have found my stupidity, coordinates are in [lon, lat] format, I was expecting them as [lat, lon].

Comment: The map is correct, believe me. [GeoJSON mandates lon, lat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html) ;-) But indeed, if you reverse lon<->lat then your point is outside of the circle around New Dehli.

Comment: yeah I believe you!!!!
answer the question, I will mark accepted :D